# Postgres trigger to update counter in another table not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

- There is `users` table and `places` table.
- The `users` table has column `id`(primary key), `username`, `place_count`.
- The `places` table has column `id`(primary key), `name`, `user_id` (user_id foreign key)
- Each user can post multiple photos and so I want the
  column"place_count" to keep the count of user-specific places from
  places table (eg, user with id 1 having place_count = 150, user with
  id 2 having place_count = 244 etc etc).

I made use of trigger

**Trigger function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION log_place_count_update_to_user()
RETURNS TRIGGER as $$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = `INSERT`) THEN
        UPDATE users 
        SET place_count = place_count + 1
        WHERE user_id;
    ELSEIF (TG_OP = `DELETE`) THEN
        UPDATE users
        SET place_count = place_count - 1 
        WHERE id = NEW.user_id AND place_count > 0;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

**Trigger creation**

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_place_count_update
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE
    ON places
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_place_count_update_to_user();
```

I have inserted some users in `users` table with initial value of `place_count` = 0.

**PROBLEM :**  When I update the places with the name and user_id I expect the trigger to increment the `place_count` by 1 in `users` table. But no increment is happening in `place_count` of `user` table.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't materialize the count. Drop the column `place_count` in `users` and the trigger. Redundant data can lead to inconsistencies. You can always query the *right* values. For convenience you can create a view that lists the users along with the count.

Comment: I dont know about views now. Just starting with postgres. But thanks for bringing it out, I'll certainly look upon views and see where it can solve my desired functionality. In the context of my approach, why is it going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: multiple syntax errors. This should work:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION log_place_count_update_to_user()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   CASE TG_OP
   WHEN 'INSERT' THEN            -- single quotes
      UPDATE users AS u
      SET    place_count = u.place_count + 1
      WHERE  u.id = NEW.user_id;  -- fixed
   WHEN 'DELETE' THEN
      UPDATE users AS u
      SET    place_count = u.place_count - 1 
      WHERE  u.id = OLD.user_id
      AND    u.place_count > 0;
   ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unexpected TG_OP: "%". Should not occur!', TG_OP;
   END CASE;
   
   RETURN NULL;      -- for AFTER trigger this can be NULL
END
$func$;
```

Your original would actually produce error messages.

And your trigger needs to address `INSERT` instead of `UPDATE`:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER log_place_count_update
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON places
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_place_count_update_to_user();
```

(`UPDATE` is not covered, yet!)

But (as has been commented) I wouldn't go there. Keeping count with a trigger is expensive and error prone.

With an index on `places (user_id)` (like you should have anyway) this query returns the current count very quickly:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM places WHERE user_id = $user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I copy pasted ur whole code snippet replacing `CREATE FUNCTION` with `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` as i had to replace my previous function. After that i inserted another set of places with user_id related to some user's id in users table. After inserting those, i still get no update on `place_count` field in `users` table

Comment: @Jake: Oh, the trigger had a bug, too. And I assume `users.place_count` is defined `NOT NULL`?

Comment: yeah users.place_count is defined `NOT NULL`. But agian before updating any place. i inserted some users and set the initial value of place_count to `0`

Comment: hey sorry for the mess. Your solution indeed solved it. Mistakenly ur `And your trigger needs to address INSERT instead of UPDATE` was skipped. It was due to i was addresing `UPDATE` instread of `INSERT`. Its working fine now. 8hours wasted lol. Very grateful to you indeed

Comment: Hey mate ur delete condition is not working. The increment count is working on insert. but the decrement count is not working on deleting a place.

Comment: @Jake: missed one more bug: delete works with OLD, not NEW.

Comment: also there is a small typo in `DELETE` part. it should be `UPDATE users AS u` intead of `UPDATE users`